# Can't catch NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, exception

First post here, so sorry if I've got some of the niceties wrong. I'm trying to catch an exception where the user enters an invalid (non-existent) employee. I've tried many different variations, but the error is never raised. Instead the code just terminates, in this case it will drop out after the following lines:

```
 MyPostSalary = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
 Console.WriteLine();
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Complete code:

```
       Console.Write("Employee ID: ");
        myEID = Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            Console.Write("Post ID: ");
            myPID = Console.ReadLine();

            if ((myEmployees[myEID] is MonthlyPaidEmployee) || (myEmployees[myEID] isWeeklyPaidEmployee))
            {

                Console.Write("Post Name: ");
                MyPostName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Post Start Date: ");
                MyPostStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Post End Date: ");
                MyPostEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Post Salary: ");
                MyPostSalary = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine();

                myPost = new Post(myPID, MyPostName, MyPostStartDate, MyPostEndDate, MyPostSalary);

                if (myEmployees[myEID] is MonthlyPaidEmployee)
                {
                    myMonthlyEmp = (MonthlyPaidEmployee)myEmployees[myEID];
                    myMonthlyEmp.PostHistory.Add(myPID, myPost);
                }

                if (myEmployees[myEID] is WeeklyPaidEmployee)
                {
                    myWeeklyEmp = (WeeklyPaidEmployee)myEmployees[myEID];
                    myWeeklyEmp.WeeklyPaidEmployeePostHistory.Add(myPID, myPost);
                }

            }

        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Employee ID does not exist.");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Comment: Your main problem is that you didn't show us the exception you're receiving or where you're receiving it.

Comment: @Daniel is right, moreover **please** do not catch an exception for an invalid user input. It's a pretty common situation (and absolutely **unexceptional**). Let's validate the input to reject it!

Comment: @John Saunders. I don't receive any sort of exception. The code simply terminates. I'm expecting it to pick up that an Employee ID  does not exist in my employees collection. I have tried the debugger and the code never seems to reach the point where it catches the error. I should say that I'm fairly new to c#!

Comment: Sounds like you're running it in release mode - in debug I think the exception is caught?

Comment: @Peopleware, I don't think it can be considered a duplicate. What he's asking for is the exact opposite, he can't catch the exception. See my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Are you in debug on Visual Studio (or your IDE)? 
If yes, it maybe you are catching the exception but the IDE is set to show a warning message when the exception raises...
Try to run your application outside the IDE, if it works you can disable warning when NullReferenceExceptions raise , but it is quite dangerous. To do this look for "Exceptions settings" in Visual Studio (or something like this, I'm not sure because I use the italian version).

Answer (score 3):

You are only catching NullReferenceException exception, but as you see in the method description of [Convert.ToDouble()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k.aspx), it throws an **InvalidCastException**.

So try `catch (InvalidCastException ex)` instead.

Also pay attention to `FormatException` and `OverflowException`.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly clear that you are *not* getting a NullReferenceException. I recommend that you try the following:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();        
}
```

Find out which exception you're receiving, and either catch that *specific* exception, or else prevent it from occurring in the first place.

You should *never* catch NullReferenceException.

Comment: It is almost always a bad idea to catch general exception

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore: I know that. This was intended for diagnostic purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you getting a double conversion exception? You should probably use Double.TryConvert rather than Convert.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the entered text can't be converted to a double.

Try catching an `InvalidCastException`.